# Free fireworks (like the effect) .NET control for WinForms or WPF?

Tags: .net, graphics, effect

Can anyone recommend a free implementation of a fireworks generating control, perhaps with sound, that can be used in .NET WinForms or WPF?

Fireworks, as in the thing that goes bang.

Comment: "Fireworks, as in the thing that goes bang." Quote of the year!

Comment: Well, he could be refering to Adobe fireworks... now it's obvious :)

Comment: What springs immediately to mind is "for the sake of all things sacred, please don't!"

Comment: If you cannot find joy in implementing this yourself then programming must be a job instead of a passion.  But kudos for injecting a 4th-of-July question into the mash.

Comment: Hans, code reuse. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a gif animation, put that in Image control and attach some sound to it -> that should be it ...  (WinForms)

Answer (score 0):

You can join this project and team with the author:

http://code.google.com/p/fireworks-screensaver/